# No access points show in Wireless

Tags: 10.10, wireless

I know when I first installed the OS it said I needed to install additional drivers. It installed Broadcom B43 legacy driver. Following what I saw in a message board I went into Synaptic and installed bcmwl-kernal-source or whatever. I went into terminal and tried installing the rfkill thing and typing rfkill unblock all - which also didn't work. I don't know what to do.

When I click on the wireless image it just says in the drop down menu `Wired network disconnected`. When I right click on it it says in the drop down menu `Enable Networking`, but it's greyed out, and `Enable Notifications` which is checked off.

The laptop I'm using is a Dell Latitude D600, if that helps.

Comment: What was the reason you followed someone's instructions on a message board? Did it work after just installing the drivers and rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Normally Broadcom wireless drivers are restricted in ubuntu. You can install it using the additional driver utility.
System->Administration->Additional Drivers.

Just active your driver in that application.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Abhijeet's answer, you can also use your wired connection to try installing the B43 firmware using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After running this command in a terminal (run one from your Applications/Accessories menu), you should find your wireless adapter is working.  It didn't need a reboot in my case, but your mileage may vary.